# Code working in IE and Chrome doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I made jQuery function that allows only numbers and one point in input `type=text`.

It works in IE and Chrome, but doesn't in Firefox. Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".inputbox").keypress(function (e) {

    //Allow only one point  
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match("[.]") && this.value.indexOf(".") != -1) {
        return false;
    }
    //Allow just numbers
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^0-9.]/g)) {
    return false;
    }

    return true;
});
});
```

Comment: I removed the PHP tag, I really don't see how it can be relevant here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem isn't in the regular expression but in `e.keyCode`. Some browsers use `keyCode`, others use `e.which`.

jQuery [handles this browser difference for you](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), making sure that `e.which` works cross-browser.